# Polygon Rasterization in Python

Tags: python, polygon, rasterizing

How to rasterize a polygon in python? for example i have this polygon:

> [(20, 13), (21, 12), (20, 12), (19, 12), (21, 13)]

This is a border and I need to find all points (tiles) inside it. How can I do it with python without any external packages?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Quick way:

```
def raster(poly):
    for index in range(len(poly) - 1):
        t1 = poly[index]
        t2 = poly[index + 1]
        xdef = t1[0] - t2[0]
        ydef = t1[1] - t2[1]
        if abs(xdef) > 1:
            lo = min(t1[0], t2[0])
            hi = max(t1[0], t2[0])
            j = lo
            while(j <= hi):
                new = (j, t1[1])
                poly.append(new)
                j += 1
        if abs(ydef) > 1:
            lo = min(t1[1], t2[1])
            hi = max(t1[1], t2[1])
            j = lo
            while(j <= hi):
                new = (t1[0], j)
                poly.append(new)
                j += 1
    return poly
```

Comment: For me this solution did not work. It does make lines connecting points (not diagonal) but that is not what the question is asking. I may not be understanding the answer correctly or how to use the function but it hasn't worked for me.